# Why is the Android Link for closed testing not updating after I have created a new release? (Google Play Console)

Tags: android, testing, console, version, playback

I have created my first App for Android and wanted to release it on Google Play Store. Sadly I had to recognize the new testing requirements.
I was uploading a first release for internal and then for closed testing. Then I recognized I have to change a small thing and created a new release on the same track. In the console the new version is showing up, but the link towards the Play store entry is still referring to the first version. So that would mean my closed testers would install an old version. How can I update this?
Or do I just have to wait until the update passed some internal queue's?